# Does serial voting reversal affect deleted content?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I recently received some serial downvotes that needed to be handled by a CM. While I was waiting for this action I deleted one of the answers that was (I believe) part of the serial downvoting. I'd gotten no feedback from the poster and I don't like having negatively scored posts. When the votes were reversed, the score on the deleted answer did not change (yes, I forced a recalculation by clicking the post score.)

Of course I don't have any way to know if this post was actually downvoted by the same user, but generally speaking: does a serial vote reversal update the votes for deleted content?

Comment: which post? and the behaviour is the same as always when it is undeleted you get the votes that are there and you can see

Comment: It depends on what action was taken, but generally yes.

Comment: @nbk I don't think the post is relevant, but [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371013/laravel-alternative-root-domain-on-verification-email-link/70371575#70371575). I'm not following the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, a serial vote reversal does update the votes for deleted posts.